# Why does the basic string formatting outperforms the built-in re.compile() function?

Tags: python, regex, performance, time, format

So I used dis library (disassembler for Python bytecode) to understand what causes such an interesting performance difference which is observed at different scales, even with 1000s of strings unlike the one string example below. However, I am still clueless.

I used both standard time library and timeit for the calculations.

```
import timeit

def find_overlapped_instances(regexx, string):
    found_any = False
    for start in range(len(string)):
        if(found_any):#addition
            break
        for end in range(start, len(string)):
            cur = string[start:end+1]
            if re.match(regex, cur):
                found_any = True
                break
    return found_any

#regex = re.compile(r'F.{4}D.AX')
regex = r'^{}$'.format(r'F.{4}D.AX') 


fasta_file = "voodoo.fasta"

total_time = 0
num_hits = 0
for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
    sequence = str(record.seq)
    starttime = timeit.default_timer()
    found_1 = find_overlapped_instances(regex, sequence)
    total_time += timeit.default_timer()-starttime
    if(found_1):
        num_hits += 1
print(num_hits)
print(total_time)
```

Formatting seems to **affect the performance in search (which is the main and nearly only source of computation) in a good way** which somehow makes a ~25% performance difference in general:

| Searching the pattern in n strings | re.compile() | r'^{}$'.format() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n = 200 | 64.3 seconds | 47.1 seconds |
| n = 400 | 136.7 seconds | 101.7 seconds |

Can someone help me understand why this might be happening?

Comment: What surprises you? If you pass "raw" regex to your function, it takes some time to compile this regex. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Yeah, I'd find this less confusing and more convincing if you presented two clear test cases, and not one case with various parts of it commented out in confusing ways.

Comment: @deceze, I updated it accordingly!

Comment: @markalex, I think you misunderstood due to the mess I had in creating the post. Could you reconsider? The part I find weird is that I pass "raw regex" to both but standard re.compile() somehow makes the re.match() (search phase) way slower.

Comment: `format` is a red herring. You can replace that with just `regex = '^F.{4}D.AX$'`, it does exactly the same thing. What probably *does* play a role is that the two regexen **aren't the same**.

Comment: @deceze, hmm... I get the result I want either way though. The findings of the search are the same. (I know this doesn't mean the regexen are the same.) 

I am really curious about what difference these regexen might have that would cause such a performance difference.

Comment: Make the two regexen the same for starters, then measure again and see if it still makes a difference. Even if the result is the same, the execution is not.

Comment: @deceze, I did not understand what you meant in your first sentence. Aren't they already the same? Compile and format gets the same thing.

Comment: No, one regex is `F.{4}D.AX`, the other is `^F.{4}D.AX$`.

Comment: Also, `num_hits` and `find_overlapped_instances` are not defined.

Comment: The main reason is that when `regex` is a compiled regex, you shouldn't do `re.match(regex, cur)`, but `regex.match(cur)`. The first expects `regex` to be a string, and so it needs to convert the compiled object to a string first (every time!), only to interpret that string again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the test should use the same regex (i.e. both with or without the `^` and `$` anchors), the main problem is that when you have the *compiled* regular expression object, you should not pass it as first argument to `re.match`, but call `match` on that object. Only then you will benefit from that compilation.

Here is a simpler test that shows this difference, using three scenarios:

1. Calling `match` on the compiled regular expression object (fastest)
2. Calling `re.match` with the pattern string as argument (medium)
3. Calling `re.match` with the compiled regular expression object as argument (worst)

Here is a script for testing that:

```
import re
import timeit

pattern = r'F.{4}D.AX'
compiled = re.compile(pattern)
s = "qsdf F9999D9AX los F999D99AX"

def test1():
    compiled.match(s)

def test2():
    re.match(pattern, s)

def test3():
    re.match(compiled, s)

for test in (test1, test2, test3):   
    print(timeit.timeit(test, number=1000000))
```

Here is the output I got when running that on repl.it:

```
0.7618284979998862
2.8180372250008077
4.692441613999108
```